# Evaluating the definite integral $\int_{-1}^1 \lfloor \arccos x \rfloor \,dx$ involving the greatest integer function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluating the definite integral $$\int_{-1}^1 \lfloor \arccos x \rfloor \,dx .$$

I tried it but unable to do as it is discontinuous. Somebody told me that you should do this by drawing graph---how?

Can anybody please give me the start?

[image]

Comment: Can you draw the graph of $\arccos (x)$ from $-1$ to $1$?

Comment: @lulu i have edited it

Comment: Ok, good.  So $\arccos(-1)=\pi$, which implies $\lfloor \arccos(-1)\rfloor=3$.  Now...how long does that function stay equal to $3$?

Comment: Any thoughts?  As you can see from looking at the graph of $\arccos(x)$, the graph of $\lfloor \arccos(x) \rfloor$ is a step function with steps of height $3,2,1,0$.  The integral is just the sum of the areas of the rectangles of those heights.  Therefore, the only problem is to determine the widths.  Your integrand has discontinuities when $\arccos(x)=3,2,1,0$ so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floor function creates a step function which can be rewritten as

$$\begin{cases}\begin{align}
[\cos\pi,\cos3]&\to3\\
(\cos3,\cos2]&\to2\\
(\cos2,\cos1]&\to1\\
(\cos1,\cos0]&\to0.\\
\end{align}\end{cases}$$

The the Riemann integral is the sum of the rectangle areas,

$$3(\cos3-\cos\pi)+2(\cos2-\cos3)+(\cos1-\cos2).$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use that arccosine is  a decreasing function, and that $\arccos(cos x)=x$ if $0\le x\le \pi$. Hence $f(x)=\lfloor\arccos x\rfloor$ is a step function, defined by:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}3 &\text{if }\quad\!{-1}\le x\le\cos 3,\\2 &\text{if } \cos 3< x \le \cos 2, \\ 1  &\text{if } \cos 2< x\le \cos 1,\\ 0 &\text{if } \cos 1< x\le 1.\end{cases}$$
You should find $\enspace 3+\cos 1+\cos 2+\cos 3$.

Comment: He wants the integral for $[arccos x]$, the greatest integer function of arccos of $x$.

Comment: @Marra: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I'll withdraw my answer.

Comment: Could you delete it then, @Bernard?

Comment: @Kari: Finally I've changed it.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of indicator functions, $$\lfloor \arccos(x)\rfloor = 3\Bbb{1}_{[-1,b)} + 2\Bbb{1}_{[b,c)} + \Bbb{1}_{[c,d)}$$ where $b$, $c$ and $d$ are the points at which the $\arccos$ graph hits $3, 2$ and $1$ $$ \implies \int_{-1}^{1} \lfloor \arccos(x) \rfloor \text{ d}x \ = \  3(b+1) \Bbb{1}_{[-1,b)} + 2(c-b)\Bbb{1}_{[b,c)} + (d-c)\Bbb{1}_{[c,d)}$$

> If you haven't yet met the indicator function, $\Bbb{1}_{[a,b]}$ simply means that we take the value $1$ when $a \leqslant x \leqslant b$ and $0$ elsewhere i.e. $$ \Bbb{1}_{[a,b]} = \begin{cases} 1 & a \leqslant x \leqslant b \\ 0 & \text{ else} \end{cases} $$

---

In more plain English, your integral is simply a sum of the areas of rectangles of widths $b+1$, $c-b$ and $d-c$ with respective heights $3, 2$ and $1$.

All you gotta do is find $b, c$ and $d$. The graph's below if you wanna have a go first and compare afterwards!

> $\hskip1in$ [image]